# ¿Cómo obtener el width?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Intento obtener el ancho de un `div` pero siempre sale el mismo valor, hice un ejemplo para `ng-repeat` obtengo el mismo valor, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

cada que incremento por cada repeat se supone que aumente el ancho como se hace eso?

> ojo sin jquery solo js puro

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "maria"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "juan"
  }]
});

var s = document.getElementById('new');
console.log(s.offsetWidth );
```

```css
#new {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block
}

#dox {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="new" ng-repeat="x in records">
      <div>{{x.id}}.- {{x.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**El width de `ng-repeat` debería ir aumentando por cada `repeat` que haga o no?**

aqui un grafico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No tiendo, el resultado es diferente. Porque dices que te da igual?

Comment: No, porque el elemento que tenga `ng-repeat` será creado en cada iteración; por lo consiguiente, `div#new` siempre tendrá el ancho que le has dado por CSS (con algunas variaciones por el modelo de caja).

Comment: @GustavoGarcía como obtener el X?, quiero obtener el ancho del div padre(X) que contenga a todos los divs creados por ng-repeat

Comment: 1. Al usar `ng-repeat` crearás tantos elementos como iteres (es decir, en este caso, tendrás dos elementos `div#new` con un div cada uno. Aquí el padre, en realidad es el div que tiene el `ng-controller`.

Comment: Como dice Gustavo los `div#new` se van repitiendo (por cierto no deberías usar `id` en ese caso porque tendrás varios iguales). El `div` padre por defecto ocupará todo el ancho, tendrías que cambiarle el `display` a `inline-block` por ejemplo o ponerle un `float` si te viene mejor para que se ajuste al tamaño de los hijos.

Comment: en vez de usar `document.getElementById`, yo usaria `angular.element("");` para que el codigo quede mas angular, puede que el `id/class` aun no este en el DOM

Answer (score 4):

El problema en tu ejemplo es que el `div` con `id="new"` es el que tiene la directiva `ng-repeat`, esto provoca que se creen `n` elementos con `id="new"`, con `JS` buscas el elemento por `id` (**pero siempre obtienes el primero**) y es por esto que siempres obtienes el mismo resultado.

### Solución simple:

Si el `div` con `id="new"` es el que necesitas que contenga los elementos creados con `ng-repeat`, entonces podrías mover dicha directiva a un `span` hijo de éste.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.records = [
    {id: 1, name: "maria"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "juan"},
    {id: 3, name: "antonio"},
    {id: 4, name: "fernando"},
    {id: 5, name: "josé"},
    {id: 6, name: "julio"},
    {id: 7, name: "marisel"},
    {id: 8, name: "julia"},
    {id: 9, name: "rosario"},
    {id: 10, name: "dolores"},
    {id: 11, name: "maria"}, 
    {id: 12, name: "juan"},
    {id: 13, name: "antonio"},
    {id: 14, name: "fernando"},
    {id: 15, name: "josé"}
  ];

  $timeout(function() {
    var s = document.getElementById('new');
    console.log(s.offsetWidth);
  });
}]);
```

```css
#new {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clear: both;
}

#new>span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="new">
      <span ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.id}}.- {{x.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Solución avanzada:

Para esperar hasta que realmente se hayan renderizado todos los elementos podrías crear una directiva (`afterRender`) para obtener el ancho.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive('afterRender', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope) {
      $timeout($scope.afterRender, 0); //Llamamos al metodo del scope
    }
  };
}]);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {id: 1, name: "maria"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "juan"},
    {id: 3, name: "antonio"},
    {id: 4, name: "fernando"},
    {id: 5, name: "josé"},
    {id: 6, name: "julio"},
    {id: 7, name: "marisel"},
    {id: 8, name: "julia"},
    {id: 9, name: "rosario"},
    {id: 10, name: "dolores"},
    {id: 11, name: "maria"}, 
    {id: 12, name: "juan"},
    {id: 13, name: "antonio"},
    {id: 14, name: "fernando"},
    {id: 15, name: "josé"}
  ];

  $scope.afterRender = function() {
    var s = document.getElementById('new');
    console.log(s.offsetWidth);
  };
}]);
```

```css
#new {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clear: both;
}

#new>span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div after-render id="new">
      <span ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.id}}.- {{x.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ademas con el `window.setTimeout` te aseguras de coger el ancho solo cuando el `ng-repeat` sea aplicado completamente

Comment: @JuniorUsca, gracias por el comentario. Me recordó que tenía que terminar de completar mi respuesta. Ahora uso `$timeout`. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Los elementos div siempre tomarán el ancho del elemento padre. Si te fijas, he tomado tu propio código y le he pintado los borders, como ves miden exactamente lo mismo porque tú no les has puesto un ancho fijo.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "maria"
  }]
});

var s = document.getElementById('new');
console.log(s.offsetWidth + 'xxxxxxxxx');

var s2 = document.getElementById('dox');
console.log(s2.offsetWidth + 'xxxxxxxxx');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid green;" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="new" ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.id}}.- {{x.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red;" id="dox">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 3):

Según entendí de que quieres poner en forma lineal lo que colocas dentro del div que contiene la información a través del `ng-repeat`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "maria"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "juan"
  }]
});

var s = document.getElementById('new');
console.log(s.offsetWidth );
```

```css
#new {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block
}

#dox {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul id="new" ng-repeat="x in records">
      <li>{{x.id}}.- {{x.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: si aumento mas elementos al array-json siempre sale 70 de ancho, deberia aumentar o disminuir segun la cantidad de elementos